# How to adjust spacing between HStack elements in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, hstack, vstack

I have added `spacer(minLength: 5)` but it takes the minLength.

How can I specify the spacing between the text?

I have attached a screenshot for reference. I want to reduce the spacing between inner HStack.

```
HStack {
    Image("Rhea").resizable().cornerRadius(25).frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("How to enjoy your life without money").bold().font(.system(size: 20))
            HStack {
                Text("Lets create")
                Spacer(minLength: 5)
                Text("3K views")
                Spacer(minLength: 5)
                Text("3 hours ago")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wait what Rhea got this far? I love the example xD

Comment: By the way this was not intentional, question was posted about 2 year ago.

Comment: the example perfectly fits the character and I am surprised how you wrote this example a year before jun 2020

Comment: If you are looking for the correct method to achieve true `space-between` behavior without hard-coded spacing regardless of the container width, I have posted a detailed answer in another thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78001794/19954370

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Add a `spacing` attribute to the `HStack` itself. For a spacing of e.g. 10:

```
HStack {
    Image("Rhea").resizable().cornerRadius(25).frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("How to enjoy your life without money").bold().font(.system(size: 20))
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("Lets create")
            Text("3K views")
            Text("3 hours ago")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can add `spacing` inside your `SwiftUI` stacks by providing a value in the initialiser, like this:

**VStack**

```
VStack(spacing: 50) {
    Text("SwiftUI")
    Text("rocks")
}
```

**HStack**

```
HStack(spacing: 50) {
    Text("SwiftUI")
    Text("rocks")
}
```

In you case you can use like below.

```
HStack {
Image("Rhea").resizable().cornerRadius(25).frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("How to enjoy your life without money").bold().font(.system(size: 20))
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("Lets create")
            Text("3K views")
            Text("3 hours ago")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For more flexibility there is also `.padding(...)`:

```
HStack(spacing: 0) {
  Text("Lets create")
    .padding(.bottom, 10)
  Text("3K views")
    .padding(.bottom, 10)
  Text("3 hours ago")
}
```

Keep in mind that currently HStacks default spacing is 10, if you dont specify any or set it to nil.

Answer (score 1):

```
//alignment is optional
   HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
        // Add your views here
        Text("View 1")
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .background(Color.blue)
        
        Text("View 2")
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .background(Color.red)
        
        Text("View 3")
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .background(Color.green)
    }
```