# SwiftUI divider taking up too much space

Tags: swift, swiftui

Some simple SwiftUI code has been showing some unexpected behaviour - as seen in the image below, the dividers appear to be adding heaps of vertical space between the content of the HStack. I wish to reduce the amount of space between the row contents and the divider. The PreviewProvider is just a VStack containing 5x SummaryDataRow.[image: img]

Comment: The default spacing of a VStack is like 8, set it to a smaller number.

Comment: And please paste your code as text.

Comment: Also: [How to adjust spacing between HStack elements in swiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56506357/8697793)